# Use Facebook login button to create a user on MySQL db with PHP

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I'm using [UserCake](http://usercake.com/) php framework to manage users on my app and I want to give my users an option to log in with Facebook.

My challenge is to integrate Facebook's js sdk with my php based app. The partial solution I found is filling and submitting a login form when a user has logged in to facebook:

```
    function facebookLoginToMyApp(response){
            $('form input[name="username"]').val(response.email);
            $('form').submit();
    }
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        facebookLoginToMyApp(response);
    });
```

So how to authenticate the user without a password?
Or is  it a mistake to do it in js sdk and I should do it with php sdk instead?

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not recommendable to use client-side scripting in those cases - it's fairly easy to manipulate the form and log-in with somebody else credentials.

As you pointed out the authentification with PHP SDK will solve that issue.